# Checking continuity and differentiability of $g(x)=\frac{x^{2}}{1+\sin^{2}(1/x)}$ extended by $g(0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

> Let
>
> $$g(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{x^{2}}{1+\sin^{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)},
>  & x\neq0\\ 0, & x=0 \end{cases}$$
>
> 1. Is g(x) continuous at 0?
> 2. Does g(x) have continuous first derivative at 0?
> 3. Does g(x) have continuous second derivative at 0?

My attempt:

1. Let's check the limit.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x^{2}}{1+\sin^{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}=0$$

That's why, (1) is true.

2. Using the definition of a derivative (reworked after Adrews's comment)

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\frac{\left(x+h\right)^{2}}{1+\sin^{2}\left(\frac{1}{x+h}\right)}-\frac{x^{2}}{1+\sin^{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\frac{x^{2}+2xh+h^{2}}{1+\sin^{2}\left(\frac{1}{x+h}\right)}-\frac{x^{2}}{1+\sin^{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\frac{2xh+h^{2}}{1+\sin^{2}\left(\frac{1}{x+h}\right)}}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{2x+h}{1+\sin^{2}\left(\frac{1}{x+h}\right)}=\frac{2x}{1+\sin^{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$

Now, checking the limit

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{2x}{1+\sin^{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}=0$$

That is, the first derivative will be continuous at 0 if $g'(0) = 0$. But

$$g'(0) = \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\frac{\left(x+h\right)^{2}}{1+\sin^{2}\left(\frac{1}{x+h}\right)}-0}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\frac{x^{2}}{h}+2x+h}{1+\sin^{2}\left(\frac{1}{x+h}\right)}=+\infty$$

Hence, (2) is false.

Comment: For your (2), you seem to be both using the general $x$ and the specific value at $0$. That is wrong. The definition is $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. You have $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(0)}{h}$. Either $x=0$ or it doesn't.

Comment: I reworked the solution of (2). Could you please check it?

Comment: The second equality for the computation of the derivative is incorrect. Also, you have to separately compute $f^\prime(x)$ for $x\ne 0$ and $f^\prime(0)$. Taking $x\to 0$ in the expression for $f^\prime(x)$ then tells you if the first derivative is continuous.

Comment: again, the derivative at $x=0$ requires you to substitute $x=0$, not just $x$. But I don't think you've compute $f'(x)$ when $x\neq 0$ correctly, either.